# How can I trigger a Java servlet function when mail is received?

Tags: java, tomcat, jakarta-ee, glassfish

I am aware that Google App Engine can [capture email and fire a function](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/mail/receiving.html), but I would like this functionality in a Tomcat, Glassfish, or any other Java server.

I would like to avoid setting up a mailbox and running a cron job every few seconds or minutes. A Java class and some server configuration would be ideal, but I have no idea where to start (or if I'm looking in the right direction for the solution). Maybe the solution is language-independent if the host can POST a url such as `/mailHandler` when a message is received.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never done this but you could maybe use [Apache JAMES](http://james.apache.org/), run it [embedded](http://wiki.apache.org/james/Embedded), and use the [Mailet API](http://james.apache.org/mailet/api/).

Comment: Thank you. I'll check it out. You said you've never done it, but do you know if it can be installed without root privileges?

Answer (score 1):

A Servlet engine knows nothing about mail. Your only solution is to have a mail server, of which most are scriptable and at that point do a call to your Servlet.

Answer (score 0):

Check [mailgun](http://mailgun.net/) - It does have some interesting support for things like that